# 18.04 Ubuntu Studio: ProRealTime won't launch Java Not Initialized

Tags: software-installation, java

I'm broken.  for 1 week I've been searching.  Maybe I'm too old to learn a new operating system.  I feel so defeated.  Why is this so difficult?

Please help me.  I've ditched Windows, and want this to work, but I can't seem to find any definitive info anywhere on how this all works.

I don't know anything about Linux, Ubuntu etc.

[ProRealTime](https://www.prorealtime.com/en/faq/help_support) (which requires Java 7 or higher) won't launch.  No idea why.  I have 11.0.6+10

So far, I' think I've updated and installed the latest Java, and now trying Iced tea but no idea what to do.

I'm studying to be a Day Trader with IG uk.  They have a PRT platform.  from within Chrome, I simply click the dropdown and select PRT.  a small window open to Launch PRT.  A download appears which is itcharts.jnlp

I also have a FataL: Launch error.  Could not launch JNLP file.  failed to initialize.

Thanks.

Comment: apologies.  I've no idea what virtualisation even means.  I'm a total noob to Ubuntu etc.

Comment: OK, which command are you entering to launch ProRealTime? What happens when you do? Please click [edit] to reply.

Comment: Hi Paul Knowles, posted my answer. Please let me know if you manage & if helpful please give it a thumbs up ;-)

Answer (score 0):

for the time being it seems you need to install and use Oracle Java for Prorealtime to work under Ubuntu 18.04. Here's the link to a Prorealtime user's description of the problem + [solution](https://www.doctrading.fr/installer-prorealtime-et-metatrader-sur-ubuntu-linux/).

Basically he says the Ubuntu installed version of Java doesn't play nice with PRT and you need to replace it:

[Oracle java installation description & download link in English](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml#download)

After you downloaded & installed Java in the folder as indicated by the link & description, you need to tell Ubuntu to open the .jnlp file with Oracle java-ws:

Launch gedit to open empty document & paste the following content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Terminal=false
Name=java-ws
Exec=/usr/java/jre1.8.0_241/bin/javaws %U
Type=Application
```

Note: path "/usr/java/jre1.8.0_241" in line "Exec" above is arbitrary, but should be the exact folder name where you chose to place the extracted folder from [Oracle Java installation link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml#download) -

Save as

> java-ws.desktop

in folder

> ~/.local/share/applications

To be sure it works, restart the desktop by logging out and logging back in or pressing Alt+F2, followed by the key r and Enter.

Now, you're ready to launch the .jnlp file. Right-click on that file & choose open with to search for the java-ws application.

Launch. You should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Wayland issue. Switch to Xorg and you should be good to go.

Took me ages to work this out!